# Upon expiration, token does not work and the api throws an "unauthorised error"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using JWT in a React + Django DRF project (Rest Framework), for the requests.. with the following library.

https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#refresh-token

The problem is that upon expiration .. the token does not work anymore and the api throws an "unauthorised error".. and I do not know what I can do from react to keep the session jwt if the user wants to enter the other day and continue working with the application. What do you think? How can I reset the expired token?

Pd: The library does not send a token-refresh as others do. I can not find another similar JWT library for Django Rest Framework.

Comment: Descriptive title

Answer (score 0):

The only way to keep the token active when the user is not is to make the token take longer to expire.

From the [documentation](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#jwt_expiration_delta):

> JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA
>
> This is an instance of Python's datetime.timedelta. This will be added to datetime.utcnow() to set the expiration time.
>
> Default is datetime.timedelta(seconds=300)(5 minutes).

To make the token last a day, add this to settings.py:

```py
from datetime import timedelta

JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA=timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: what is this used for? 'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7)

Comment: As I said in my answer, it's a setting that will set the amount of time your tokens last before they expire. If you set it to `days=7`, the token will last for seven days.

Comment: 'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=1) its another that JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA, i dont know why they put a ..REFRESH_EXPIRATION.. variable